# Invalid use of non-static data member

Tags: c++

I want to create a file in which I can add Persons to a PersonList including a counter that makes sure that the capacity of the PersonList is not exceeded. I commented all the functions to make clear what task(s) they should perform.

During compilation I get the following error:

```
invalid use of non-static data member 'PersonList::m_Capacity'
```

Unfortunately I cannot figure out what's wrong in the code:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Person.h"
#include "PersonList.h"

int main()
{

    Person p1 = Person("John", 21);
    Person p2 = Person("Elham", 19);
    PersonList p_list = PersonList();

    p_list.add(p1);
    p_list.add(p2);

    std::cout << p_list.get_Size() << std::endl;
    Person p = p_list.get(0);
    std::cout << p.get_Name() << " " << p.get_Age() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Person.h

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

class Person
{
    public:
        Person();
        Person(std::string Name, int Age);

        void set_Name(std::string name);
        void set_Age(int age);
        std::string get_Name();
        int get_Age();

    private:
        std::string m_Name;
        int m_Age;
};

#endif // PERSON_H
```

Person.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include "Person.h"

Person::Person(){}

Person::Person(std::string Name, int Age){
// pre:  0 <= Age
// post: m_Name, if pre Name (is true) Age = m_Age,
//       otherwise age = -1

    set_Name(Name);

    if (0 <= Age){

        set_Age(Age);
    }

    else{

        set_Age(-1);
    }

}

void Person::set_Name(std::string Name){
// post: m_Name = Name

    m_Name = Name;
}

void Person::set_Age(int Age){
// pre:  0 <= Age
// post: if pre Age (is true) = m_Age, otherwise m_Age = -1;

    if (0 <= Age){

        m_Age = Age;
    }

    else set_Age(-1);
}

std::string Person::get_Name(){
// post: returns name

    return m_Name;
}

int Person::get_Age(){
// post: returns age

    return m_Age;
}
```

PersonList.h

```
#ifndef PERSONLIST_H
#define PERSONLIST_H

class PersonList
{
    public:
        PersonList();

        void add(Person p);
        void set_Size(int Size);
        int get(int index);
        int get_Size();

    private:
        const int m_Capacity;
        const Person m_Empty;
        Person m_Data[m_Capacity];
        int m_Size;

};

#endif // PERSONLIST_H
```

PersonList.cpp

```
#include "Person.h"
#include "PersonList.h"

PersonList::PersonList()
m_Capacity(10), m_Empty(Person())
{
// post: has created a new PersonList-object with
//      CAPACITY elements and size = 0

    set_Size(0);
}

void PersonList::add(Person p){
// pre:  size < CAPACITY
// post: if pre (is true) p has been stored at the
//      first empty location. size was incremented.

    if (m_Size < m_Capacity){

        m_Data[m_Size] = p;
        set_Size(m_Size+1);
    }

}

void set_Size(int Size){

    m_Size = Size;
}

int PersonList::get(int index){
// pre:  0 <= index && index < size
// post: if pre returns data[index] otherwise returns EMPTY

    if (0 <= index && index < m_Size){

        return m_Data[index];
    }

    else{

        return m_EMPTY;
    }
}

int PersonList::get_Size(){
// post returns size;

    return m_Size;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ does not support variable length arrays (VLAs), which is what you have here:

```
Person m_Data[m_Capacity];
```

For this to work, `m_Capacity` must be a compile time constant.

Besides that, you have a syntax error in your default constructor, where a `:` is required to indicate an initialization list:

```
PersonList::PersonList() : m_Capacity(10), m_Empty(Person()) { .... }
//                       ^ Here!
```

Comment: @Zasz It is constant for each `PersonList` instance, but it is not a compile time constant.

Comment: @juanchopanza Can you also tell me what exactly a compile time constant is, and why the const int in my code is not such a constant?

Comment: @Pietair a compile time constant is known at compile time, for example `const int i = 42`. This particulat `i` is `42` and the compiler can replace all occurrences of that `i` by the value `42`. Your `const` data members cannot be changed once they are initialized, but each instance of `Person` has a value of `m_Capacity` that can be set at run time.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor and the initialization list has to be separated by a colon. Like this

```
PersonList::PersonList() : m_Capacity(10), m_Empty(Person())
```